# Accesing Hdfs from Spark gives TokenCache error Can't get Master Kerberos principal for use as renewer

Tags: authentication, hadoop, kerberos, apache-spark

I'm trying to run a test Spark script in order to connect Spark to hadoop.
The script is the following

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
file = sc.textFile("hdfs://hadoop_node.place:9000/errs.txt")
errors = file.filter(lambda line: "ERROR" in line)
errors.count()
```

When I run it with pyspark I get

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
>   o21.collect. : java.io.IOException: **Can't get Master Kerberos
>   principal for use as renewer**
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:116)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodesInternal(TokenCache.java:100)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.obtainTokensForNamenodes(TokenCache.java:80)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:187)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:251)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:140)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.getPartitions(MappedRDD.scala:28)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
>           at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.getPartitions(PythonRDD.scala:46)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:207)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:205)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:205)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:898)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:608)
>           at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$class.collect(JavaRDDLike.scala:243)
>           at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD.collect(JavaRDD.scala:27)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
>           at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:379)
>           at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
>           at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>           at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>           at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:207)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

This happens despite the facts that

- I've done a kinit and a klist shows I have the correct tokens
- when I issue a ./bin/hadoop fs -ls hdfs://hadoop_node.place:9000/errs.txt
  it shows the file
- Both the local hadoop client and spark have the same configuration file

The core-site.xml  in the spark/conf and hadoop/conf folders is the following
(got it from one of the hadoop nodes)

```
<configuration>
    <property>

        <name>hadoop.security.auth_to_local</name>
        <value>
            RULE:[1:$1](.*@place)s/@place//
            RULE:[2:$1/$2@$0](.*/node1.place@place)s/^([a-zA-Z]*).*/$1/
            RULE:[2:$1/$2@$0](.*/node2.place@place)s/^([a-zA-Z]*).*/$1/
            RULE:[2:$1/$2@$0](.*/node3.place@place)s/^([a-zA-Z]*).*/$1/
            RULE:[2:$1/$2@$0](.*/node4.place@place)s/^([a-zA-Z]*).*/$1/
            RULE:[2:$1/$2@$0](.*/node5.place@place)s/^([a-zA-Z]*).*/$1/
            RULE:[2:$1/$2@$0](.*/node6.place@place)s/^([a-zA-Z]*).*/$1/
            RULE:[2:$1/$2@$0](.*/node7.place@place)s/^([a-zA-Z]*).*/$1/
            RULE:[2:nobody]
            DEFAULT
        </value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>net.topology.node.switch.mapping.impl</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.net.TableMapping</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>net.topology.table.file.name</name>
        <value>/etc/hadoop/conf/topology.table.file</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
        <value>hdfs://server.place:9000/</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
      <value>kerberos</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hadoop.security.authorization</name>
      <value>true</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.hosts</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>

    <property>
      <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hive.groups</name>
      <value>*</value>
    </property>

</configuration>
```

Can someone point out what am I missing?

Comment: Do all the Spark slaves also have the configuration?

Comment: Spark runs in a pseudo-distributable mode so there is only one server/node

Comment: You would still have a couple JVMs running: your application, the Spark master, the Spark worker and the executor. I think your application and the executor will be the ones accessing HDFS, so you need to make sure they have loaded the right configuration. You could print `System.getProperties` on the executor to check.

Comment: Good idea. I'll do this next time I face a problem. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After creating my own hadoop cluster in order to better understand how hadoop works.  I fixed it.

You have to provide Spark with a valid .keytab file which has been generated for an account which has at least read access to the hadoop cluster.

Also, you have to provide spark with the hdfs-site.xml of your hdfs cluster.

So for my case I had to create a keytab file which when you run

> klist -k -e -t

on it you get entries like the following

> host/fully.qualified.domain.name@REALM.COM

In my case the host was the literal word host and not a variable.
Also in your hdfs-site.xml you have to provide the path of the keytab file and say that

> host/_HOST@REALM.COM

will be your account.

Cloudera has a pretty detailed writeup on how to do it.

**Edit**
after playing a little bit with different configurations I think the following should be noted.
You have to provide spark with the exact hdfs-site.xml and core-site.xml of your hadoop cluster. Otherwise it wont work

Comment: Could you please add the link to Cloudera writeup?

Comment: http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/documentation/core/latest/topics/cdh_sg_kerberos_prin_keytab_deploy.html

Comment: What parameter name you use to connect fro Spark to HDFS with Kerberos