# Using keytab file in spark standalone program

Tags: scala, kerberos, apache-spark

I am trying to access a file from HDFS in my standalone scala program using apache-spark. I get the following error upon execution.

```
SIMPLE authentication is not enabled.  Available:[TOKEN,KERBEROS]
```

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23238443/accesing-hdfs-from-spark-gives-tokencache-error-cant-get-master-kerberos-princi) question that explains that i need to create a keytab file and then make my standalone program use it . I have generated the keytab file . Could somebody tell me how i can use it from my program.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

ps - I am using Hadoop 2.3.0 and spark 0.9.0

update : this is how my core-site.xml looks now :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera Manager-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://USHadoop</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>fs.trash.interval</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
    <value>kerberos</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.rpc.protection</name>
    <value>authentication</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.auth_to_local</name>
    <value>DEFAULT</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: did you configure any authentification proprieties for your Hadoop cluster?

Comment: @eliasah could you tell me how to do that exactly because i am not sure .

Comment: in your configuration files, did you add any property to your `hdfs-site.xml` that asks for authentification? btw can you update your question with the versions of Hadoop and Spark that you are using?

Comment: @eliasah No i did not. I only know that something needs to be added but i do not know what !

Comment: Can you add your `core-site.xml` file?

Comment: @eliasah i have added it in the question

Comment: The last 3 properties are generating the errors. You might consider taking them out and let me know what happens

Comment: Make sure your datanodes are configured to use kerberos as well. You can get these errors when namenode configured to use kerberos receives unauthenticated requests from datanodes